# flatMap is not a function in Angular Universal; misconfigured tsconfig.server.json?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm having trouble using [Array.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) in Angular Universal.  The client-side code works fine, but the Angular Universal complains about flatMap not existing:

```
let x = data.flatMap(d => d.value)
ERROR TypeError: data.flatMap is not a function
```

I'm guessing the `tsconfig.server.json` is misspecified, but the parameters are very similar to what I used for the client-side version:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom",
      "esnext.array"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: How did you declare `data`?

Comment: @David `data` is coming from an API; it is an array and it does exist.

This minimal example also gives an error:
`let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]; arr1.flatMap(x => [x * 2]);`

Comment: I think it's supported in es2019/ nodejs11

Comment: @David, thanks, it's definitely supported in es2019. Adding `esnext.array` seems to work client-side but not server-side with Angular Universal.  Not sure why.  In any case, I can switch over to lodash's `flatMapDeep` and avoid the issue.